# How do I listen for the operating system click event in node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am building an electron app where you can highlight a phone number where ever: email, browser, word etc... then right click and click on a custom menu item, then node would add that phone number to a list. I'm having trouble finding the documentation for the "node" click event, everything I'm finding is the browser or window click event. However I need this to happen regardless of the application I'm in. What is this called? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That's not possible, there's no such thing. You can't influence the behaviour of another application which isn't yours. What if those applications have their own right-click behaviour - what should happen in that case? Should it be overriden by what your node app has specified? Or both events should happen? That could cause a bit of a mess. Your concept is flawed, sorry. I could be wrong but I'm 99% sure that unless you control the O/S itself you can't implement this, and even then it would have the potential to cause total chaos.

Comment: I see, could it work with a keyboard shortcut where the app "listens" for the keyboard short cut... copies the highlighted text and then puts it on the list?

Comment: Depends on the OS, on linux you can "subscribe" to any perihperie events, on Windows not, neither sure about OSx

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of research I came up with an acceptable solution, ADyson put me on the right path. Here is the resulting code if anyone needs to do something similar:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, clipboard } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const robot = require('robotjs');
const Notification1 = require('node-mac-notifier');

//removed opening window because it is irrelevant.

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    globalShortcut.register('Cmd+Shift+S', () => {
        robot.keyTap('c', 'command');
        const number = clipboard.readText();
        new Notification1(`${number} added to DNC`, {});
        //Number logic here
    });
});
```

If you are using electron you have to rebuild both the robotjs package and the node-mac-notifier packages here is how you do that:

in the terminal:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
npx electron-rebuild -f -m node_modules/node-mac-notifier
npx electron-rebuild -f -m node_modules/robotjs
```

You might get a "no gyp or clt detected" error when rebuilding the packages, here is how you fix that:

```
xcode-select --print-path
sudo rm -r -f <path>
xcode-select --install
```